# usb_cam package framerate can't increase on Rasp Pi 3B+

Tags: usb-cam

I am using a [Raspberry Pi 3B+](https://www.reichelt.de/raspberry-pi-3-b-4x-1-4-ghz-1-gb-ram-wlan-bt-raspberry-pi-3b--p217696.html?CCOUNTRY=445&LANGUAGE=de&PROVID=2788&&r=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjw9MCnBhCYARIsAB1WQVXcxLLiy3rt0dVtzsWpUQqCYb0UDDhe-lTDzcMP7hH-SvxNr3NxuyEaAqOwEALw_wcB) with a Raspberry camera.

The operation system is Ubuntu-mate 20.04 and I am running ROS1 noetic on it. To be able to use the camera, I followed the instructions [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2124560#p2124560) to enable to camera.

I tried using the [usb_cam package](http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam) with a desired framerate of 30 fps @ 640*480. This is the default settings of the demo usb_cam_test.launch. Nothing else is running.

When I tried `rostopic hz /usb_cam/image_raw`, the topic only updates about 7-8Hz, which is supposed to be 30 as expected.

---

To study the problem's nature, I tried a few other combinations

- usb_cam package demo + PC with ubuntu 20.04: 30 fps no problem
- usb_cam package demo + Raspberry PI 4B with Ubuntu 18.04: 30 fps no problem
- [uvc_camera package](http://wiki.ros.org/uvc_camera) + Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Ubuntu 20.04: only 7-8 fps max

So this looks to me like the problem is with the Raspberry Pi 3B+. But it also confuses me that 30 fps at this low resolution is shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This isn't a question which can easily be answered. There is likely a bottleneck. Are you CPU, memory, or network bandwidth limited? What else is running on your system? Can you provide a minimum working example such that someone can reproduce the problem (full hardware, and installation process)? Please edit your question to add these extra details.